# Celdas dinámicas de excel en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel, php7

sucede que necesito exportar una plantilla de excel generada desde php con algunos datos que extraigo de una tabla en una base de datos,  hasta ahí no es problema.  Mi problema comienza cuando necesito que una de los campos del excel tenga múltiples opciones (como un select option)  así como muestro en la imagen:
[image: Ven como el campo de servicios/productos tiene select]

Gracias por ayudarme o al menos darme una luz de cómo lo podría hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Debes definir la celda como tipo `LIST`, pensando que la celda es `D1` el código va más menos así para crear una :

```
$oLista = $sheet->getCell('D1')->getDataValidation();
$oLista->setType(\PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
$oLista->setAllowBlank(false);
$oLista->setShowInputMessage(true);
$oLista->setShowDropDown(true);
$oLista->setPromptTitle('Una Lista');
$oLista->setPrompt('Selecciona un elemento de esta lista.');
$oLista->setErrorTitle('Error en la lista');
$oLista->setError('Este valor no existe');
```

Y al final puedes agregar los elementos con:

```
$objValidation->setFormula1(implode(',', ['"elemento1,sub1"', '"elemento2,sub2"', '"elemento3,sub3"']));
```

También ser puede poner un rango de celdas en la formula.

Comment: Gracias, lo intentaré :)

Comment: No hay de que. No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta en caso de que solucione el problema para cerrar el ciclo de la pregunta